# JSON Array - PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get the URL of a thumbnail from YouTube's History JSON feed. I have the key and can browse the JSON in my browser.

Feed: http://pastebin.com/mePrYhxK

I can't seem to be able to get anything.

```
$json = file_get_contents('YouTubeJSONURLincludingkey');
$data = json_decode($json,true);
$url = $data->{'items'}[0]->{'snippet'}->{'thumbnails'}->{'medium'}->{'url'};
echo $url;
```

Right now, getting nothing.

Comment: You passed `json_decode` `true` as a second param, so things are arrays,not objects.

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump` on `$data`, and each child of it? When you say you're not getting anything, what do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing `true` to the second argument of [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) indicates you want it to return an array.

You might be able to get better results doing:

```
$url = $data['items'][0]['snippet']['thumbnails']['medium']['url'];
```